# Is a spatial index on a ST_Transformed geometry simply ignored when the transformation has the same target CRS than CRS of the geometry?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-index

I have such vanilla index on a [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX polygons_gix
    ON public.polygons
    USING gist (geom);
```

Because of this:

> If using more than one transformation, it is useful to have a functional index on the commonly used transformations to take advantage of index usage.
> https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html

I also need:

```sql
CREATE INDEX polygons_gix
    ON public.polygons
    USING gist (ST_Transform(geom, XXXX)); -- where XXXX is any EPSG code for your transform
```

Now, depending on the local CRS, I need many of these transforms, (which I may not know in advance but this is another problem... so let's say I know them; I can write 40x that Index for 40 regions having 40 different CRS).

To reduce this story to a minimum, I have to make it 'stupid', in a way: so let's say, my geometries are given for a "master" region which serves as the default, e.g. `EPSG:2154`.

Would the following index be evaluated or not?
(and if yes, will this consume some extra time or resources?)

```sql
CREATE INDEX polygons_gix
    ON public.polygons
    USING gist (ST_Transform(geom, 2154));
```

I know this story is nonsense, so this is more out of curiosity. I already fixed the code that led me to this strange situation when I noticed it (the EPSG code value was injected automatically).

Comment: I don't have a postgis database handy on my current machine but I think you could check something like this by inspecting the execution plan by prepending the query with `EXPLAIN` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-explain.html)

Comment: While possible, and indeed useful for singular cases, having *many* (functional) indexes on the same column(s) is in many ways something to avoid. Naturally, each of them need a physical storage and equal resources to maintain and update. Additionally, transformations may not be lossless. I suggest to instead only ever transform to a (close or underlying) geographic CRS (e.g. `EPSG:4326`) and use the `GEOGRAPHY` type, either directly as column, or via a single functional index (`... ON (geom::GEOGRAPHY);`).

Answer (score 4):

No, the index would be considered, as you invoke a matching expression, and that expression will get executed with all consequences (luckily `ST_Transform` would make an early exit in this case).

An index on an expression stores the *computed value* of the given expression, not the computation. It doesn't care if `ST_Transform` internally determines that it won't need to do anything, and just returns a copy of the input geometry as its retrun value.

Furthermore, PG expects a *new object* of type `GEOMETRY` from that expression, so the 'vanilla' index cannot get considered!